# Setting up dependencies for publish tasks

Tags: gradle

I programmatically create maven-publish publications and would like those to depend on a custom task. I have tried the following:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

publishing.publications.create("A", MavenPublication) { groupId = "G" }

task t

afterEvaluate { publishToMavenLocal.dependsOn(t) }
```

Doing a `gradle publishToMavenLocal` does result in `t` running before `publishToMavenLocal` but the generated task, `publishAPublicationToMavenLocal`, runs before `t` which is not what I want. I have tried setting up dependencies by iterating all tasks with names beginning with publish. This does not work either since `publishAPublicationToMavenLocal` is not available in the `afterEvaluate` phase.

Comment: Hi, have you resolved this on?

Comment: No, I no longer need to publish artifacts, so I haven't pursued it any further.